# Serialization of the full page DOM. Can I get at the JS code that is loaded up, or must I AJAX it separately?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web-applications

I have a bug I'm trying to track down, and it is very difficult to do so because of the complexity of the web app. There are many frames, and many instances of Javascript code that is embedded into the HTML in different ways.

The thing that needs to be fixed is a sub-page created with `showModalDialog` (so you already know it's going to be a disaster), and I am hoping that I can find a way to serialize **as much of the DOM as possible** within this dialog page context, so that I may open it to the same content both when the bug is present and when it is not, in hopes of detecting missing/extra/different Javascript, which would become apparent by pumping the result through a diff.

I tried `jQuery(document).children().html()`. This gets a little bit of the way there (it's able to serialize one of the outer `<script>` tags!) but does not include the contents of the iframe (most of the page content is about 3 iframe/frame levels deep).

I do have a custom script which I'm very glad I made, as it's able to walk down into the frame hierarchy recursively, so I imagine I can use `.html()` in conjunction with that to obtain my "serialization" which I can then do some manual checking to see if it matches up with what the web inspector tells me.

Perhaps there exists some flag I can give to `html()` to get it to recurse into the iframes/frames?

The real question, though, is about how to get a dump of **all** the JS code that is loaded in this particular page context. Because of the significant server-side component of this situation, javascript *resources* can be entirely dynamic and therefore should also be checked for differences. How would I go about (in JS on the client) extracting the raw contents of a `<script src='path'>` tag to place into the serialization? I can work around this by manually intercepting these resources but it would be nice if everything can go into one thing for use with the diff.

Is there no way to do this other than by separately re-requesting those JS resources (*not* from script tags) with ajax?

Comment: +1 for being really hard

Comment: document.write the code from document.documentElemement.outerHTML. you can't reliably rip JS code from memory because a lot of modules unpack themselves upon loading, discarding browser compat shims and alternate configs along the way.

Comment: `outerHTML` seems to provide me about as much info as `innerHTML`, it just has the outer tag on it. I think I can get away with assuming the non-inline JS code is static in my particular situation

Comment: I came up with something half-assed, because the code to splice the child frames' content into the HTML of the main page, where they "would go", was just gonna be too difficult. I basically just flattened the hierarchy and stuck it on the end. Seems to work. The markup is nearly identical though so I clearly need to do some more work, however I have a feeling this tool could come in handy for sanity-checking. I'm now hoping the dynamic script resource can yield the answer next.

Comment: I know it's a bit late now, but any word on this?

Comment: Yeah the word is, I left the company... Two years ago. But really at some point one simply needs more powerful tools to combat these abominations of design.