# DOM MutationObservers: How to support this one important use of DOM3 Mutation Events?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, mutation-observers

I get wordy sometimes: tl;dr: read the bold text.

The motivation behind deprecating Mutation Events is well understood; their efficacy in achieving many types of tasks is questionable.

However, today, I have discovered a use for them that is highly dependent on those very same undesired properties.

I will first present the question, and then present the reasons that lead me to the question, because the question will be absurd without it.

**Is it possible to use the new Mutation Observers in a way that we can have the VM stop at the instant of the change (like the DOM3 Mutation Events do), rather than report it to me after the fact?**

Basically, the very thing that makes the Mutation Observer performant and "reasonable" is its asynchronicity, which means (necessarily, it seems) throwing away the stack, pushing a record mutation to a list, and delivering the list to qualified Observers at the next tick or several ticks later.

What I am after is precisely that stack trace of the DOM3 Mutation Event. I really really hope this will work, but basically the Mutation Event callback (which I am allowed to write) will have a stacktrace that will lead me back to the *actual code* that created my element I'm listening for. So in theory I'd write a Mutation Event handler like this:

```
// NOT in an onload cb
$("div#haystack").on('DOMNodeInserted', function(evt) {
  if (is_needle(evt.target)) {
    report(new Error().stack); // please, Chrome, tell me what code created the needle
  }
});
```

This gives me the golden answer.

It seems that Mutation Observers will make it impossible to extract this information. **What, then, am I to do once Mutation Events are completely taken out?** They have been deprecated for a while now.

Now, to explain a little better the real actual circumstances, and why this matters.

I have been trying to kill a bug which [I describe here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17681541): I have built a full-DOM serializer which nicely spits back out every element that exists on the webpage, and in comparing them, the broken page and the working page are identical. I have tested this and it is pretty nice. it captures every little thing that's different: Whatever hovery-thing my mouse happens to be over, the CSS class that gets consequently set will be reflected in the HTML dump. Any text of any form on the page will show up if you search it (provided it doesn't span across elements). All inline JS (and more importantly, all differences between inline JS) is present.

I have then gone on to verify that the broken page is missing several event handlers. So none of the clickable items respond to hover or clicks, and therefore no useful work can be done on the interactive form. This is not known to be the only problem, but it does fully explain the behavior. Given that the DOM has no differences in inline JS that explains the difference in behavior, then it *must* be the case that either the content of the linked resources or the invisible properties of elements (event handlers being in this category) are causing the difference in behavior.

Now I know which elements are supposed to have handlers, but I know not where in the comically large code base (ballpark: 200K lines of JS all loaded as one resource, assembled by several M lines of Perl serverside code) lies the code that assigns the events.

I have tried JS methods to watch modifications of object properties, such as [this one](https://gist.github.com/eligrey/384583) (there are many, but all work on the same principle of setting setters and getters), which works the first time, and then subsequently *breaks* the app afterward. Apparently assigning setters and getters cause the system to stop functioning. It's not clear to me how I can take that approach of watching property assignments to a point where i can get a list of code points that hit a specific element. It *might* be feasible, but surely not if I can only fire it *once*, and it breaks everything thereafter.

So watching variables with JS is out.

I might be able to manually instrument jQuery itself, so that when my `is_needle()` succeeds on the element processed by jQuery, I log all event-related functions performed by jQuery on that element. This is dreadful, and I will resort to this if my Mutation Observer approach fails.

There are yet more ways to skin the cat of course. I could use the handy `getEventListeners()` on my target element when it is working to get the list of event listener functions that are on it, and then look at the code there, and search the code base to find those functions, and then analyze the code to find out all the places there those functions are inserted into event handlers. That is actually pretty straightforward.

Comment: I think you've answered your own question. Mutation Observers are specifically designed not to be synchronous, so use cases which require immediate, synchronous notification of DOM mutation are simnply not covered by Mutation Observers.

Comment: Well, so since Mutation Events are deprecated and will be removed, what will I do once that happens?

Comment: I think you're pretty much screwed. Sorry.

Comment: Make your life easier. Shadow `node.appendChild` and `node.insertBefore`. (You'll probably find the ones you'll be interested in on `HTMLElement.prototype`)

Comment: @PaulS. that's terrifying... but i guess it's a neat hack.

Answer (score 0):

> Now I know which elements are supposed to have handlers, but I know not where in the comically large code base (ballpark: 200K lines of JS all loaded as one resource, assembled by several M lines of Perl serverside code) lies the code that assigns the events.

Have you considered simply instrumenting **.addEventListener** function calls one way or another, e.g. via debugger breakpoints or by modifying the DOM element prototype to replace it with a wrapper method? This would be browser-specific but should be sufficient for your debugging needs.

You also might want to try firefox's tracer, available in nightlies I think. It basically records function execution without the need to use breakpoints or instrumenting code.